# NgbDropdown doesn't stay open

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I want to have a login dropdown in my navbar. However, as soon as something within the login form is clicked, the dropdown closes.

Another question: How can I make the dropdown appear aligned with the toggle on the right side? Right now it left-aligns with the toggle.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li *ngIf="!user" class="nav-item dropdown float-xs-right">
        <div ngbDropdown autoClose="false" class="d-inline-block pull-left">
            <a class="nav-link" id="loginDropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ngbDropdownToggle>Login</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="loginDropdown">
                <login></login> <!--The login component, it's just a form-->
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: if you are using bootstrap I would suggest switching over to the official bootstarp for angular 2. I was having issues and switched over. its found here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: I'm using ng-bootstrap (NgbDropdown).

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to have an input within your dropdown?

Comment: Yes, I have a form with two inputs, a button and some links in it.

Comment: did my answer help??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are looking for the `[autoClose]` directive. Here is the official doc https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown as well as a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xiiYQqrP9OIdtOF7ifUO?p=preview

here is the relative code from the plunker

```
<div ngbDropdown class="dropdown d-inline-block" [autoClose]="false" >
```

Comment: Great, I missed the square brackets. Now the the dropdown stays open until the toggle is clicked again. Is there a way to close it when the user clicks outside (but not inside) the dropdown?

Comment: I dont see any type of functionality meeting those requirement on the official docs.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `autoClose` with value `"outside"`

```
<div ngbDropdown [autoClose]="'outside'" >
```

The dropdown will close only on the outside clicks and not on menu clicks.